# PRAW: How to get a reddit comment object with just the comment ID?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm working on a bot where I only have the comment IDs, e.g., t1_asdasd. I don't have access to the parent thread or anything. Can I pull the corresponding comment object with just the comment ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This reddit thread shows how to accomplish this through the normal API: http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1si9m0/fetching_comments_by_id/

Here's the code to do this with PRAW:

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="bot by /u/{0}".format("YOUR-USERNAME")) 
submission = r.get_info(thing_id="t1_asdasd")
print(submission)
```

Answer (score 5):

praw.Reddit doesn't seem to have .get_info() anymore, so the answer above is no longer valid

Found that this returns the required comment:

```
comment_id = some_comment.id.split("_")[1]
praw.Reddit(required credentials).comment(id=comment_id)
```